# Best way to instantly mirror/sync files from Windows to Linux server

Tags: file, synchronization, mirroring

I have a directory on a Windows machine with a large number of files and folders that I need to watch and have the files mirrored/synced instantly (or as near to as possible), to a Linux machine over the local network.

I've investigated:
- Rsync, not realtime enough
- WinSCP 'Keep directories up to date' feature, which was OK but limited to 500 directories and the performance was pretty slow.

There are a bunch of results of shareware-style apps that claim to do this, but they are all pretty dubious looking. It seems there must be a good FOSS solution somewhere?

UPDATE: I'd be happy with a one-way transfer rather than a full sync, as long as it's instant and automatic.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I am struggling with the same thing... it seems that a technology to be able to develop on windows with the server in a vm in linux + FAST doesn't exists.... (I said FAST so docker is not an option sadly)

Comment: Your question included the answer to my question.  thanks!

Comment: @user38561 - Sorry to ping you on this question. I can't leave a comment on a deleted question. Read the close reason for your question. It says your question may be on-topic at [Super User](http://superuser.com/).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I second eneset's proposal of the Unison software. Also if you care of looking for some alternatives Lifehacker has an interesting article on this subject http://lifehacker.com/372175/free-ways-to-synchronize-folders-between-computers

titel

Answer (score 6):

Have a look at Unison (http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/). I successfully used it for Linux/Windows home directory mirroring.

Comment: Thanks, but it looks like it would have the same issue as rsync, it only runs periodically.

Comment: @Vinko -- problem is, often times we need it sooner: Ctrl+S in the IDE, hit refresh on the browser. Need it to be able to sync text files in like 5 seconds or less to be tolerable.. and file sharing via ssh / ftp / etc is not always tolerable as most IDEs have very poor remote directory performance.

Answer (score 6):

It seems that what you want is to actually deal with the files on the linux server as if they were local files on your computer.

Did you consider looking for a tool to mount a remote ssh folder as a local drive?

Comment: I can access the files using Samba, that's fine. The reason I want to work locally is that Eclipse has performance problems working over samba, which I am trying to address by working locally and only have the files transferred when changed.

Comment: What about something like Webdrive that mounts (S)FTP or SSH locally on a Windows machine as a drive letter and mirrors changes up to the server? I use it when developing perl or PHP scripts for a web server on a Windows machine http://www.webdrive.com/products/webdrive/ it's not free, but you might find some free tools like Webdrive

Answer (score 3):

Have you considered using [Samba](http://samba.org)? It will let you mount windows shares under linux  as well as accessing linux directorys from windows if you set them up as shares.

Comment: Hi Jared, same applies as above. Samba works but performance is an issue in this case.

Comment: Exactly. Unfortunately Samba is soooo sloooow